# Wordpress Post Name Permalinks 404

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I am getting 404 errors on a wordpress site using the post name permalink setting.

I usually find the cause of this to be the apache mod_rewrite to not be enabled. However in this case it is.

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I also have AllowOverride All set in the virtualhosts file.

I'm not sure of any other possible causes of this error, can anyone advise? The site is a subdomain if that makes any difference.

Comment: whats your `.htaccess` file permission ? also changing `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` does that  help ?

Comment: Permissions are 775, changing that doesn't appear to have helped.

Comment: Is the whole site in the root directory?

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Please make sure you have actually `enabled mod_rewrite`. At your terminal prompt, enter the following:

**sudo a2enmod rewrite**

**sudo service apache2 restart**

**2)** And edit the **None** to **All**

> AllowOverride None ---> AllowOverride All

**sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that, it will work fine.